# ng-route with phonegap loading correct view even if the templateUrl doesnt exist

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I am using ng-route to load the partial templates inside my phonegap app. I did a `$location.path('/assessments')` to load a specific partial 'assessments.html'.

`//..snippet

```
$routeProvider
.when('/assessments', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/assessment.html',
    controller: 'AssessCtrl'
})`
```

I know from the logs that the controller AssessCtrl is being called. It's also showing the correct assessment.html on the iPad.

However, if in the filesystem I change the name of the assessment.html file to xyz.html, it still loads the correct template.

How can I make sure the template is being loaded from the iPad and not being returned from the server (which I hit to get the data).

Comment: The template + your javascript file is probably just being stored in your browsers cache on the ipad, try changing the file name and accessing again on incognito mode (or Safari's equivalent if you are on Safari)

Comment: It's actually from inside the cordova wrapped application, I am not running it from the browser. So is there something wrong that I am doing that you see above, which I can fix.